# Mount NTFS (read/write capability) filesystem on RHEL 5 (2.6.8-18.el5)

Tags: linux

I'm using RHEL 5.0 with the kernel 2.6.8-18.el5.
I want to mount my external hard disk drive with the NTFS file system.
I cannot mount it because it doesn't support NTFS file system.
Error msg: mount: unknown 'ntfs' file system.

Can anyone tell me to mount this hard disk?

Regards,

Sarith

Answer (score 1):

You would be better off asking this on https://serverfault.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Install the ntfs-3g package as it contains a working NTFS driver for Linux. Afterwards mount using the command: "mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda1 /mnt/windows"

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
However, I cannot find the ntfs-3g package appropriated for the RHEL 5.0 kernel 2.6.18-8.el5.

Comment: Why don't you try to compile the sources of ntfs-3g? ( http://www.ntfs-3g.org/index.html#installation). A Kernel recompile will surely do it. But, do you really want to get to that level?

Comment: @Sarith: You'll find that in the rpmforge repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Niels' answer, if you are able to install ntfs-3g package, then use following command, works flawlessly for me on redhat with windows partition:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda9
```

where /dev/sda9 is your windows partition. 
Before doing this make sure to:

-> Start windows, restart it and login to redhat linux instead of windows.

You might also want to look into bios settings if above ntfs-3g driver doesn't work.